Problem with Fitch : How to Eliminate ¬∃?
fitch problem:

I've been working on a Fitch-style proof problem, and I've encountered a difficulty in a specific step (step 11). The problem restricts me to using Taut-Con rules from Con-Rules. Here’s where I’m stuck:
I need to eliminate ¬∃ from ¬∃x ¬Cube(x), so I could use Disj.-Elimination, but every attempt I've made results in a message from Fitch saying I’m using the wrong sentence. This has left me confused about how to proceed within the subproof.
Could someone please guide me on the correct approach to eliminate ¬∃x ¬Cube(x). Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

i know step 15 should be ∃x Cube(x), just took wrong screenshot

@MauroALLEGRANZA steps 1 and 2 are premise and goal is the very last line saying goal (∃x Cube(x))

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! It helped a lot, but Fitch says now the subproofs does not end with the same sentece, which they actually are... or i'm missing something?
https://imgur.com/a/oo3MfuG

nevermind, i got it myself! Thanks again!!!

Here is the complete proof: ${}$


Hint
If 1 and 2 are the premises and the goal is $∃x \text {Cube}(x)$, in order to solve the issue with Disjunction Elim in step 11 you have to assume $¬ \text {Cube}(x)$ and derive a contradiction with $¬∃x¬ \text {Cube}(x)$.
Having a contradiction, use it with Double Negation to conclude with $\text {Cube}(x)$. The result will follow by Existential Intro.
